Fetch close of business share price through VB.NET
I am after a code to fetch close of business prices for any particular instrument/share through YahooFinanceAPI or any other code through VB.NET
I have find below similar post but the issue I am getting is with "GetWebResponse" as VB.NET doesn't recognize it.
Retrieve the historical close price for each stock from yahoo finance?
Thanks
' Get the prices for this symbol.
Private Function GetStockPrices(ByVal symbol As String) As _
    List(Of Single)
    ' Compose the URL.
    Dim url As String = _
        "http://www.google.com/finance/historical?output=csv&q=" _
        & symbol

    ' Get the result.
    ' Get the web response.
    Dim result As String = GetWebResponse(url)

    ' Get the historical prices.
    Dim lines() As String = result.Split( _
        New String() {vbCr, vbLf}, _
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim prices As New List(Of Single)()

    ' Process the lines, skipping the header.
    For i As Integer = 1 To lines.Length - 1
        Dim line As String = lines(i)
        prices.Add(Single.Parse(line.Split(","c)(4)))
    Next i

    Return prices
End Function 


Did you download the zip file from VB Helper that contains the GetWebResponse function?

The following may be of interest: Exchanges, NYSE Listings, AAPL (Google), AAPL (Yahoo), AAPL Historical (Yahoo), AA (Google).

Almost no one uses http anymore. Any reputable company uses https now. It's unlikely that you're going to make it very far if you're not able to identify that the URL in the code, which you took from an old post, is no longer valid.


The Google and Yahoo finance APIs are no longer publically available. 2) Stack Overflow is not a programming service.


Maybe Nasdaq's API AND ANALYSIS TOOLS FOR TABLES DATA will give you somewhere to start.

See the comment by @kikon of this post which contains some C# code which may be helpful.
